# How to pass the user and password in code itself

Tags: java

I have an api which needs authorization for access. But I want to pass the authorization in code itself so that I do not need to enter the user id and password each time I use.

```
String[] apiList = { "https://example.com" };
String user, pass;

System.out.print("Enter your username:");
user = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter your Password:");
pass = input.nextLine();

if (user.equals("user") && (pass.equals("password"))) {
    System.out.println("welcome");
} else {
    System.out.println("please try again!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String user = "myusername";
String pass = "mypassword";
```

And remove the code which asks for user input, this way you don't have to enter it every time.

I'd only do this if it were a personal project without source control, you don't want to commit usernames and passwords to repositories *especially* not public repositories.

---

An alternative would be to store this data in a text file somewhere and load it into those variables, this text file can be outside the repository folder or you can `gitignore` this file.

---

Another way would be to use `args` inside the `main` method eg:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String user = args[0];
    String pass = args[1];

}
```

Then you can configure them as commandline arguments in your IDE or pass them on the terminal when running your program.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it should simply say -- never store usernames and passwords in source code.  Period. Full Stop.

Comment: @JasonArmstrong Fair enough, I agree it shouldn't be part of permanent code, the answer does specify why it's a bad idea though. For quick tests to play around with an API I would argue it's not as bad.

Comment: I agree your rationale is ok and I've done it myself. I've since broken that habit because it's too easy to forget about it -- say I'll fix it later and then don't. It's better to develop discipline early and stick with it and encourage others to do the same.